# Can the List component be used in an edit form?

Tags: input, associations, relationship, admin-on-rest

I want to be able to bring a dataset into an edit/create form because I need the respective resource in order to associate it to the main model.

Say, a store has many employees. I want , from an ui perspective, to be able to add employees to the store.

I am able to to this via a custom component, however **I want to know if I am able to use the List component to fetch a certain resource**, ,because I have a feeling that I'm not doing this properly now. Adminonrest has the tools to render a paginated list of resources, so how can I make better use of these tools ? Then make a custom iterator to represent the model anyway I want to (maybe even use the datagrid component). I can then attach custom actions.

What would the best pattern for this situation be ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, this feature is not supported. You can display employees, using the [`ReferenceManyField`](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Fields.html#referencemanyfield) but we don't support creating them from the Edit page.

Comment: I understand. So, using the internals of adminonrest how can I display the employees. I can create my own custom actions to perform the requests, and I can use the restclient itself to make the request, or create a custom saga. However, how can I display the list of employees using whay aor gives me, and not fetch the customers in the custom component manually. Thanks :)

Comment: Edit my answer with a link to the component to use